# simple update (SQL) vs bulk update (PL/SQL)

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, bulkupdate

Recently I came across an interview question about :
which is a better and faster was of updating a table in oracle DB for more than 1 Million records and why ?
simple update :

```
update employee
set salary = salary + (salary*5%)
where dept_id = l_dept_id
```

or

using bulk collect and forall statement as this :
`

```
declare 
type t_ntt is table of employee.employee_id%TYPE; 
l_ntt t_ntt; 
l_dept_id INTEGER := 10; 
c_limit INTEGER := 10000; 
cursor c is select employee_id from employee where dept_id = l_dept_id; 
begin 
open c; 
loop 
fetch c into l_ntt limit c_limit; 
exit when l_ntt.count = 0; 

forall I in indices of l_ntt 
update employee 
set salary = salary + (salary*5%) 
where employee_id = l_ntt(I); 
end loop; 
close c; 
commit; 
end;
```

`

Comment: I'm a little confused.  How does a bulk collect and forall statement modify the data?  There would need to be an `update` (or `merge`) involved somewhere.

Comment: A good read for your understanding. https://www.orafaq.com/node/2450

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks for the guidance :)